# Fading android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, user-profile

I want to create a profile activity which toolbar should look somehow like this: 
[image]

So far I have this:
[image]

Also I don't understand how to get rid of this shadow or overlay effect, maybe this would already solve my problem.

activity_activity_profil.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.appmac.ron.app_newsfeed.ActivityProfil">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_color"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_profil" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar_color.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#7b7b7b"
        android:endColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

UPDATE: 
The Shadow is gone, now i would like to make my Toolbar transparent, like this:

[image]

I have this right now:

[image]

If more code is needed just tell me and I'll update it. 
Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the elevation to `0dp` on your `AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

You might want to move the background to the `AppBarLayout` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! I updated my post, do you also have some advise for that? @Eugen Pechanec

Comment: As I said move the background from Toolbar to AppBarLayout. It should be a gradient from #4000 to #0000. Put the content view (the scroll view) behind the CoordinatorLayout and set paddingTop to `?actionBarSize`. You better post another question though.

Comment: I've got this fading color effect that helped, but I wanted to make it also transparent so that you can see the content scrolling behind the toolbar :/ @Eugen Pechanec